# How to use matplotlib to plot pyspark sql results

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark. I want to plot the result using matplotlib, but not sure which function to use. I searched for a way to convert sql result to pandas and then use plot.

Comment: Hi Team I have found the solution for this. I converted sql dataframe to pandas dataframe and then I was able to plot the graphs. below is the sample code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution for this. I converted sql dataframe to pandas dataframe and then I was able to plot the graphs. below is the sample code.from

```
pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
import pyspark
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
test_list = [(1, 'hasan'),(2, 'nana'),(3, 'dad'),(4, 'mon')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(test_list)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(id=int(x[0]), name=x[1]))
schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people)
# Register it as a temp table
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(schemaPeople, "test_table")
df1=sqlContext.sql("Select * from test_table")
pdf1=df1.toPandas()
pdf1.plot(kind='barh',x='name',y='id',colormap='winter_r')
```

Comment: If the data is too huge and if Pandas doesn't support bigger data, what can we do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For small data, you can use `.select()` and `.collect()` on the pyspark DataFrame. `collect` will give a python list of `pyspark.sql.types.Row`, which can be indexed. From there you can plot using matplotlib without Pandas, however using Pandas dataframes with `df.toPandas()` is probably easier.