# How to use matplotlib to plot pyspark sql results using shell

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark

I know the question has been asked before regarding using matplotlib in pyspark. I wanted to know how to do the same through shell. I used the same code as given in this solution

[How to use matplotlib to plot pyspark sql results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003301/how-to-use-matplotlib-to-plot-pyspark-sql-results)

However I am getting this when I run in the shell.

```
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f1cd604b690>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I do understand your question, so please provide more details in case I got you wrong.

If you happen to see an instance of a Subplot-Class such as given by you, rather have the previous command's return value assigned to a variable, because otherwise you cannot use it. I will give a simple example of a subplot below:

In essence, instead of:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
```

do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.show()
```

If this didnt answer your question, please provide a minimal working example of what you are doing.