# How to use a for-loop in a spark dataframe?

Tags: for-loop, pyspark

I would like to for loop over a pyspark dataframe with distinct values in a specific column. It appears that it does not work in the same way as using pandas in python. How can I achieve this?

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
+---------+
|val1|val2|
+---------+
|1   |10  |
|2   |11  |
|1   |10  |
|2   |12  |
|3   |13  |
|1   |15  |
|1   |11  |
|1   |16  |
|3   |17  |
|3   |18  |
|2   |12  |
|2   |11  |
|3   |14  |
|1   |19  |
|1   |17  |
+---------+
```

and I would like to make a histogram of val2 for each distinct val1 (1,2,3).

How am I able to do this using a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Spark is distributed so any plotting is going to require moving the data to your driver machine. You can do the aggregation in spark, but at some point you'll have to call a collect operation.

Comment: See also: [Pyspark: show histogram of a data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154325/pyspark-show-histogram-of-a-data-frame-column/47137405#47137405) and [How to use matplotlib to plot pyspark sql results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003301/how-to-use-matplotlib-to-plot-pyspark-sql-results).